# Scoring Formula with Positive/Negative Rank

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, t-sql

I'd like to make a linear score formula that I can use in a view. I'm having trouble working out the logic though.

Data:

```
*UserID (int)| *WidgetID (int)| Rank (int) | IsPreferred (bit)
1            | 1              | 1          | 1
1            | 2              | 2          | 1
1            | 3              | 3          | 1
1            | 4              | 1          | 0
1            | 5              | 2          | 0
2            | 1              | 1          | 1
```

User #1 loves Widget #1 the most and hates Widget #4 the most. User #2 just loves Widget #1 (the most).

I would like the my view to look something like this:

```
*UserID (int)| *WidgetID (int)| Rank (int) | IsPreferred (bit) | Score (int)
1            | 1              | 1          | 1                 | 3
1            | 2              | 2          | 1                 | 2
1            | 3              | 3          | 1                 | 1
1            | 4              | 1          | 0                 | -2
1            | 5              | 2          | 0                 | -1
2            | 1              | 1          | 1                 | 1
```

The Rank always (for now) has an absolute between 1-5 (inclusive). UserID and WidgetID are both primary keys and the application forces consecutive unique ranks so I don't have to worry about conflicting scores. I thought of doing something like this:

```
Select *, Case When IsPreferred = 1 Then (5 / Rank) Else -(5 / Rank) End As Score...
```

But that's exponential and could cause problems if we allow for more then 5 rankings in the future...

I'm hoping I don't have to do this in my application, cause that's not very `l33t`. I'm thinking `PARTITION` or `RANK` may be able to help me out but I haven't had any success yet.

Anybody got any ideas? Thanks

**UPDATE** see my answer [below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8436425/585552)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works, but I'm open to other ideas:

```
SELECT    UserID, WidgetID, Rank, IsPreferred, Rank() over (Partition BY UserID  order by Rank DESC) as Score
FROM         dbo.Table
Where IsPreferred = 1
Union
SELECT    UserID, WidgetID, Rank, IsPreferred, -1 * Rank() over (Partition BY UserID  order by Rank DESC) as Score
FROM         dbo.Table
Where IsPreferred = 0
ORDER BY UserID, Score
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you really need to do that in SQL? I'm thinking this kind of formula, as it's complex business logic, would really be better in actual code, depending on your application's language. I don't know about your environment, so it's difficult to recommend that, but I know I would definitely do that in my application layer, not in the database layer.

Benefits would include better readability, testability (you could write unit-tests to make sure your ranking formula works as expected), etc.